# Success rate based on date

Tags: excel-formula

I'm a total excel noob. I'm trying to find "Today's Success rate" based on 2 columns. One column is the date of an attempt, the other is success/fail. I have a formula for getting the overall success rate, but it just uses one column. I need to get today's success rate. There are other columns, but don't worry about those.

The problem I'm having is finding a different column cell value from a result of searching the date column. SO, find today's date in column A, then sum up the true values from column B and divide by total.

```
| Date Col A    | Success Col B |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| 4/1/2019      | true          |
| 4/1/2019      | false         |
| 4/2/2019      | true          |
| 4/2/2019      | false         |
| 4/2/2019      | true          |
| 4/2/2019      | false         |
| 4/2/2019      | false         |
```

This is the formula I have for calculating the overall success rate

```
=100*COUNTIF(B2:B1000,"true")/SUM(COUNTIF(B2:B1000,"true"), COUNTIF(B2:B1000,"false"))
```

Assuming today is April 2, 2019, the above table should have
Today's Success Rate: 40%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With text values in cols **A** and **B**, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="4/2/2019")*(B:B="true"))/SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A="4/2/2019"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. I did change it to make the static date a cell value with =TODAY() in it, though. If D2 contains =TODAY()

=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=D2)*(B:B="true"))/SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=D2))

Answer (score 1):

`=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$9,$D$2,$B$3:$B$9,TRUE)/COUNTIF($A$3:$A$9,$D$2)`

This should work. I put "today's date" in cell D2 so make sure you adjust the formula accordingly. Another thing to note is make sure that your true false entries in column B are in the same format as it is in the formula (meaning all caps or no caps).